# I'm getting this error "InvalidOperationException was Unhandled"

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

[enter image description here][1]The idea is after i logged in. i want the full name,address,phone be visible in the payment form. I need to finish my system before Wednesday. I really tried looking online i just can't understand it much. if you have any ways to deal with this error please tell.   ![[image]][1]

[I did this just now and still got an error. [][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM6y1.png)

[here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vvv7.png)

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: The exception **tells you** whats wrong - the connection needed by hte DbCommand object has not been inititalized.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]; This is not the right way to ask a question here - in fact you didnt ask one at all..

Comment: Sorry. i'm a newbie .Please bear with me.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain sorry I dont know . i just got the source code oline.